# MSBuild CL Task output directory

Tags: c++, msbuild

i am writing a MSBuild script which compiles a C++ file using MSBuild CL Task, something like:

```
<CL Sources="c:\temp\myfile.cpp" />
```

How do i control where the output (myfile.obj) goes? By default, it goes to the path from where the script is present (and also happens to be the path from where i run the script): i.e. if i run the script (*c:\someFolder\build.proj*) from *"c:\someFolder\"* then myfile.obj is placed at *"c:\someFolder\myfile.obj"*.

Going by a wild (illogical) guess, i also tried fidgeting with OutDir property(?!), something like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutDir>d:\somePlace\<OutDir>
</PropertyGroup>
...
<CL Sources="c:\temp\myfile.cpp" />
```

Didn't work.

Comment: ObjectFileName argument.  This approach is unwise, the CL task has a *lot* of arguments.  Consider using the ClCompile task instead so MSBuild takes care of invoking CL and properties like IntDir and OutDir actually have an effect.  See how it is used by the .vcxproj file that the IDE generates.

Comment: Isn't CLCompile a target? Which Assembly file would i have to mention in the UsingTask tag? i was unable to find any related information on the internet regarding CLCompile Task..?

Comment: Yes, target.  It is defined in Microsoft.Cpp.targets, pulled in automatically by a `<Import>` element in a .vcxproj file.

Comment: Why would using the ObjectFileName argument be unwise? After all i am using a "bare metal" approach.

Comment: have you looked at what's inside Microsoft.Cpp.targets? You should see your 'bare metal' approach will quickly lead to an unmaintainable hell :P Is there a reason you can't just use a (minimal) msbuild file based on a standard vcxproj?

Comment: Hahaha :) i think we cannot use a standard vcxproj. This is primarily because we are linking different tool chains (embedded) using MSBuild. Why do we need CL Task then? Because for each unit test we want to build a Win32 executable as well because running unit tests off-target is faster than running them on-target. Anyways i'll have a look inside the Microsoft.Cpp.targets and report back.

Comment: A normal vcxproj gives you a plain Win32 executable which seems exactly what you need then? All you need to do is copy an empty C++ project, create an ItemGroup named ClCompile and populate it with your source files, set some compiler properties and invoke the Build target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the original question about how to control the output of the CL task is by using the ObjectFileName argument (as provided by Hans Passant).

However, it now seems that using a minimum standard vcxproj is a better idea (as suggested by both stijn and Hans Passant).